# CSS background shorthand property not working with background-size

Tags: css

When I try to combine several lines of CSS into one when styling a background image like so:

```
background: url("img/background.jpg") cover no-repeat;
```

It doesn't work; however, when I move the cover and no-repeat onto their own lines

```
background: url("img/background.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

The image works just fine. Any hints or ideas on what's going wrong? I often notice this problem with things like padding and margins as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `background` shorthand requires that you also set `background-position` in order to set `background-size`. You can find the grammar for the `background` shorthand in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background), but in a nutshell the syntax for the two properties is

```
<bg-position> [ / <bg-size> ]
```

which means "`background-position`, optionally followed by a forward slash then `background-size`" (the usual optional-whitespace rules apply)

If you do not need to change `background-position` to a different value, the initial value is `0 0` (zero on both axes):

```
background: url("img/background.jpg") 0 0 / cover no-repeat;
```

Comment: I just tested your answer in Chrome but didn't work! message: `Invalid property`

Comment: @Super Hornet: Got a fiddle?

Comment: @Super Hornet: Are you sure you tested it correctly?

Comment: worked perfectly for me. Bolt could you explain what the forward slash is for? Is it just the specs or does it mean something?

Comment: @Anindya Basu: I believe it's to distinguish the two properties, as each of them can accept two numeric values, e.g. `0% 0% / 100% 100%`.

Answer (score 2):

`background-size` should not be included in `background` because it is not recognized by browsers.

Comment: so background: url("insert url") no-repeat; background-size: cover; would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @AnindyaBasu yes exactly

Comment: @AnindyaBasu : Yes, here is a good link for shorthand reference
http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/

Comment: @harsha: That was published in 2005. 9 years ago. It's long out of date now. Not a good link at all.

Comment: thanks for the help Hornet, going with bolt's answer because it's a shorter and slightly better solution. I appreciate your quick response though

Answer (score 2):

If in longhand you're using a single value keyword (top, left, etc.) and letting the unwritten one default to center it won't work in shorthand. You need to specify both keyword values.

```
background: url("image.jpg");
background-position: left;
background-size: cover;
```

In shorthand you will have to specify both values..

```
background: url("image.jpg") left center / cover;
```

Or both center..

```
background: url("image.jpg");
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;

background: url("image.jpg") center center / cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this for the logo

```
background: url('img/logo.png') center center / contain no-repeat;
```

and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the properties in the shorthand declaration is the bg-size property, you must use a / (slash) to separate it from the bg-position property, e.g. background:url(smiley.gif) 10px 20px/50px 50px; will result in a background image, positioned 10 pixels from the left, 20 pixels from the top, and the size of the image will be 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels high.

`background: bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat bg-origin bg-clip bg-attachment initial|inherit;`