# What does "canonical order" mean with respect to CSS properties?

Tags: css, terminology

MDN's pages about CSS properties ([example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)) and some of the CSSWG's specifications ([example](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property)) make reference to the "canonical order" of the property.

For example, MDN says the canonical order of `display` is:

> the unique non-ambiguous order defined by the formal grammar

and the CSSWG's flexbox spec says the canonical order of `flex` is:

> per grammar

Every CSS property seems to be listed on MDN as having a canonical order; canonical order is also mentioned in the entertaining [CSS Foo Module Level N](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-module-bikeshed/) specification that CSSWG uses as a template for new property specifications.

What does this mean, and where is the meaning specified (if anywhere)? I haven't managed to track down a definition of the term online, nor can I think of any obvious guesses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grammar of a property refers to the syntax for a value of said property in a CSS declaration. Most properties take a single value, but some properties take multiple values in set orders, for example `box-shadow` and `background-repeat`, as well as shorthand properties. This grammar is usually seen directly in the "Value:" line but may be elaborated in the prose, for example if the property takes a comma-separated list of such complex values.

For example, the grammar of the [level 3 `background` shorthand](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background) is defined as zero or more `<bg-layer>`s followed by one `<final-bg-layer>`, where

```
<bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box>
<final-bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box> || <'background-color'>
```

The two `<box>` values are described as follows:

> If one `<box>` value is present then it sets both ‘background-origin’ and ‘background-clip’ to that value. If two values are present, then the first sets ‘background-origin’ and the second ‘background-clip’.

And the `||` delimiters between each component mean that [one or more of those components can occur and in any order](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values-3/#comb-any). In the case of `background`, notice that `background-position` and `background-size` do not have a `||` between them; this means [the two properties need to appear together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682193/css-background-shorthand-property-not-working/24682494#24682494) (and for `background-size` to be specified, `background-position` *must* be included).

For example, the following two declarations are valid and equivalent:

```css
background: url(see-through.png) center / 100% no-repeat fixed padding-box red;
background: red url(see-through.png) fixed padding-box no-repeat center / 100%;
```

---

No specification appears to define the term "canonical order", but CSSOM makes a number of references to it in the context of serialization. For instance, in [section 5.4.3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#the-cssstylerule-interface) it says:

> The ***specified order*** for declarations is the same as specified, but with shorthand properties expanded into their longhand properties, in canonical order.

The values of these longhands are serialized for the purposes of [`getPropertyValue()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-getpropertyvalue), [`setProperty()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-getpropertyvalue), [`setPropertyValue()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setpropertyvalue) and [`setPropertyPriority()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setpropertypriority), all of which refer to the "canonical order" as well.

Not every property has a canonical order, since as mentioned above most properties take only a single value anyway; the "Canonical order:" line is present in the lone propdef table in css-module-bikeshed simply because it's a template. Furthermore, CSSOM seems to imply that only shorthand properties have a canonical order.

Based on my understanding of the relevant specifications, when the canonical order of a shorthand property is defined as the grammar of that value, it simply means that its longhands should be serialized in the order that is defined by the grammar. So the above two shorthand declarations should be serialized in the exact same order as the following set of longhand declarations:

```css
background-image: url(see-through.png);
background-position: center;
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
background-color: red;
```

(On an interesting note, the shorthand-to-longhand mapping examples given in the Backgrounds module do not appear to follow this order.)

Comment: *Scratches feeble head.* Thank you, I will reread this thoroughly after work once I've got some time to follow the links and make sense of it all. Things I immediately wonder after reading this (and without fully understanding it) are: why does MDN list a canonical order for every single property if most don't have one; do any properties have a canonical order that is not "per grammar"; and what actual effect does the canonical order have from a web developer's perspective, if any? Perhaps some of these thoughts are stupid - I haven't had a chance to digest this properly yet, but will later.

Comment: @Mark Amery: No clue about MDN, but coincidentally `display` is promoted to shorthand in the [css-display](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-display) module, so having a canonical order would make sense there. Serialization is mostly an implementation detail, so if it had any impact on authors it would be if they depended on it. But don't take my word for it either ;)